# Remote repository from GitHub to Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse

I found online a couple of ways to import a remote repository to Eclipse, but none of them work. Whenever I try to connect remote repository with the local one, this error stops me.

[image: No project found]

If I try a different option other than "Import existing Eclipse project", like "Import using the new project wizard" or "Import as general project"), it also doesn't work for different reasons.

EclipseSource website suggest the following:

> Please note that there needs to be existing projects in your repository, and if you use your own repository it might be empty, so you have to create an initial branch.

The problem is that I don't really understand what to do, since every single tutorial doesn't mention anything like that and I'm not familiar with git at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. I cloned the remote repository without creating an additional project and after that, I right clicked to the Working Tree of my current repository and then "import projects".

It seems that the problem wasn't an non-existed project. I still don't know why the classic way doesn't work, but at least the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The repository you are cloning needs to have a pre-existing eclipse project, it can't just be generic code. If you want general code, you'll need to clone it into the folder manually.

In a terminal, navigate to the folder with your project in it where you want the code, and run `git clone [url]`, replacing [url] with the url of the remote repository.